# Checkbox can't be unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, checkbox

I am currently trying to solve a problem with my jquery and my html form.

Problem: I have a checkbox that allows people to check to accept or not accept the terms and conditions. This checkbox is being validated by a jquery function, named validateAccept(). However, after i insert the if valid return true and if not valid return false, the checkbox become unresponsive to clicking. I am a beginner with jquery. I am not sure which part went wrong.

my HTML code:

```
<form action="<? echo $filename; ?>" id="acceptanceForm" name="acceptanceForm" method="post">
  <p>Terms and conditions.......</p>
  I ACCEPT THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS
  <input type="checkbox" name="accept" id="accept" value="yes"/>
  <span id="acceptInfo" class="inputInfo"></span>
</form>
```

My jQuery validating code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Validation (TERMSANDCONDITION)
//termsandconditions variables
var acceptanceForm = $("#acceptanceForm");
var accept = $("#accept");
var acceptInfo = $("#acceptInfo");

//Trigger validation
//On blur
accept.click(validateAccept);
//On key press
accept.keyup(validateAccept);
//On submit
acceptanceForm.submit(function () {
    if (validateAccept()) 
        return true
    else 
        return false;
});

//Validation
//validate accept

function validateAccept() {
    var isChecked = $('#accept').is(':checked');
    if (isChecked) {
        accept.removeClass("error");
        acceptInfo.text("Thanks");
        acceptInfo.removeClass("error");
        acceptInfo.removeClass("inputInfo");
        acceptInfo.addClass("validated");
        return true;
    } else {
        accept.addClass("error");
        acceptInfo.text("Please Read and Accept the Terms and Conditions");
        acceptInfo.removeClass("inputInfo");
        acceptInfo.removeClass("validated");
        acceptInfo.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I know:
I know that the problems lies with the return true and return false that I added in. I tried without them on JS Fiddle and the check box is working but the form is not. Therefore, I know that return true and false is necessary but I don't really know how I should sort them out to make it work. I have did some researched and realised that little little cases similar to mine. This validation technique is suppose to work on text input so I am not sure if the way i edit it is alright to work for checkbox.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JdRb/3/)

Comment: I can check and uncheck the checkbox in your Fiddle, isn't this what you asked?

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle

Comment: @Hatsjoem I forgot to include jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that returning false in a click handler prevents the default behavior.  If you need to use this in both situations, but ignore the return value in the case of the click handler, you could do this:

```
accept.click(function(){
    validateAccept();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8JdRb/1/

In this case the click handler function has no return value and does not affect the functioning of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I can use `.change(validateAccept);` instead. It would work exactly the same as I wanted to. Thanks all.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JdRb/4/)